# printing truth table confusion

Tags: f#

I'm trying to understand the code from the book **Programming F# 3.0** by Chris Smith.

The following code prints the truth table for the given function.

```
> // Print the truth table for the given function
let printTruthTable f =
    printfn "  |true | false |"
    printfn "  +-------+-------+"
    printfn " true | %5b | %5b |" (f true true) (f true false)
    printfn " false | %5b | %5b |" (f false true) (f false false)
    printfn " +-------+-------+"
    printfn ""
    ();;

val printTruthTable : (bool -> bool -> bool) -> unit
```

A sample output..

```
> printTruthTable (&&);;
       |true   | false |
       +-------+-------+
 true  | true  | false |
 false | false | false |
       +-------+-------+
val it : unit = ()
```

However, I do not understand the following line

```
    printfn " true | %5b | %5b |" (f true true) (f true false)
```

In my mind it seems it should resolve to (which doesn't make sense)

```
    printfn " true | %5b | %5b |" (&& true true) (&& true false)
```

But this does does not execute.

Could someone explain this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is resolved to

```
printfn " true | %5b | %5b |" ((&&) true true) ((&&) true false)
```

Which prints

```
true |  true | false |
```